# How to remove highlight form JProgressbar

Tags: java, swing, awt, jprogressbar

[image]

I haven't been able to find a way to remove the highlight and keep my the black line border. Setting `.setBorderPainted(false)` fixes the highlight but also removes my border. Is there a way this can be fixed with `look and feel` or `UIManager`?

Code:

```
    this.downloadProgressBar.setBounds(16, 16, 512, 32);
    this.downloadProgressBar.setBorder(this.blackBorder);
    this.downloadProgressBar.setForeground(Color.pink);
    this.downloadProgressBar.setOpaque(false);
    this.downloadProgressBar.setString("75%");
    this.downloadProgressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    this.downloadProgressBar.setMinimum(0);
    this.downloadProgressBar.setMaximum(100);
    this.downloadProgressBar.setValue(75);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the default PLAF UI with a basic progress bar UI that does not have the pesky highlights as such:

(using a temp variable for more easily readable code):

```
JProgressBar bar = this.downloadProgressBar;
bar.setUI((ProgressBarUI)BasicProgressBarUI.createUI(bar));
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH